# Explanation of Scoping with regards to lambda in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, scope

I have seen an example of a lambda function where the lambda body calls out to a method NOT passed in the capture group. I think this has something to 'reaching scope' described here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda.

Q1) How is possible for a lambda body to 'see' beyond the body and capture group?
Q2) Can someone explain reaching scope a little clearer?
Q3) Can someone explain 'block scope' as well?

As far as I understand, 'block scope' is some type of closure type. A closure type is some grouping of code, but
Q4) What are the rules of determine the bounds of a 'closure type'?

```cpp
void foo()
{
   ...    //do something
}

int main()
{
    [](){
       ...   //do something
       foo() //how is this lambda function able to call foo()?

    }

}
```

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: Only automatic variables need to be captured. Functions and global variables don't, since they have fixed memory locations.